# Swift protocol requring method returning protocols

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, protocols

I am trying to make following code compile.
Basically I want to have object conforming multiple protocols, for example network service that exposes different groups of API to different parts of app (for example: login API to loginController, sharing API to shareController)

+

I want this service to be injected using networkXProvider protocols e.g. implement Dependency Injection (for example I want to pass to LoginController an Injection that adopts LoginControllerProvider and FetchingUsersFromDBProvider):

```
protocol MyAccountCommunicator {
    func getAccountData() -> String
}

protocol EventsCommunicator {
    func getEvents() -> String
}


 class NetworkManager: MyAccountCommunicator, EventsCommunicator {
    func getAccountData() -> String {
        return "Accounts"
    }

    func getEvents() -> String {
        return "Events"
    }
}

protocol MyAccountCommunicatorProvider {
    var networkCommunicator: MyAccountCommunicator { get }
}


protocol EventsCommunicatorProvider {
    var networkCommunicator: EventsCommunicator { get }
}

class Injector: MyAccountCommunicatorProvider, EventsCommunicatorProvider {
    var networkCommunicator: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()
}
```

Playground fails with following error:

> error: strings.playground:29:7: error: type 'Injector' does not
>   conform to protocol 'MyAccountCommunicatorProvider' class Injector:
>   MyAccountCommunicatorProvider, EventsCommunicatorProvider {
>         ^
>
> strings.playground:30:9: note: candidate has non-matching type
>   'NetworkManager'
>       var networkCommunicator: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()
>           ^
>
> error: strings.playground:29:7: error: type 'Injector' does not
>   conform to protocol 'EventsCommunicatorProvider' class Injector:
>   MyAccountCommunicatorProvider, EventsCommunicatorProvider {
>         ^
>
> strings.playground:30:9: note: candidate has non-matching type
>   'NetworkManager'
>       var networkCommunicator: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()

Environment: swift4, XCode9

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need MyAccountCommunicatorProvider and EventsCommunicatorProvider protocols? What if you combine them into one?

```
protocol CommunicatorProvider {
 var networkCommunicator: NetworkManager { get }
}

class Injector: CommunicatorProvider {
   var networkCommunicator = NetworkManager()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for question, I've updated text of initial question so It might be easier to understand what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
    protocol MyAccountCommunicator {
    func getAccountData() -> String
}

protocol EventsCommunicator {
    func getEvents() -> String
}

protocol MyAccountCommunicatorProvider {
    var accountCommunicator: MyAccountCommunicator { get }
}

protocol EventsCommunicatorProvider {
    var eventCommunicator: EventsCommunicator { get }
}

class NetworkManager: MyAccountCommunicator, EventsCommunicator {
    func getAccountData() -> String {
        return "Accounts"
    }

    func getEvents() -> String {
        return "Events"
    }
}

class Injector: MyAccountCommunicatorProvider, EventsCommunicatorProvider {
    var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    var accountCommunicator: MyAccountCommunicator {
        return networkManager
    }

    var eventCommunicator: EventsCommunicator {
        return networkManager
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it is a solution, but the point is to be able to return full object without need to create a method for every protocol

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
protocol MyAccountCommunicatorProvider {
    var networkCommunicator1: MyAccountCommunicator { get }
}

protocol EventsCommunicatorProvider {
    var networkCommunicator2: EventsCommunicator { get }
}

class Injector: MyAccountCommunicatorProvider, EventsCommunicatorProvider {
    var networkCommunicator: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()
    lazy var networkCommunicator1: MyAccountCommunicator = {
        return networkCommunicator
    }()
    lazy var networkCommunicator2: EventsCommunicator = {
        return networkCommunicator
    }()
}
```

Comment: thanks, it is a solution, but the point is to be able to return full object without need to create a method for every protocol